# Find value of $x$ which minimizes $f(x)=ax^4+bx+c$, where $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}$ and..

Tags: analysis, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

## Problem

Find value of $x$ which minimizes $f(x)=ax^4+bx+c$, where $(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R}$ and find conditions a,b and c satisfy in order for the function to have a unique and finite minimum.

## Solution

Critical points can be found rather easily when, $f'(x)=0$ which happens when

$$ x=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{b}{4a}} $$

Whether the critical point is minima or maxima it can be determined with sign of second derivative therefore if $f''(x)>0 \implies$ minimum, which means that

$$ 12a\left(\sqrt[3]{-\frac{b}{4a}}\right)^2 > 0 \implies \text{ minimum} $$

In order for the function to have unique and finite minimun conditions,
$a \neq 0$ and $a \cdot b \le 0$ must be satisfied. Since $\frac{b}{a} \le 0$ in order to the square root to be real-valued this must be met and dividing with zero is not defined hence $a \neq 0$.

---

However the conditions in order to the function have unique and finite minima appears to be wrong? Any explanation how how exactly this is wrong?

Comment: You need $a>0$ or $(a,b)=(0,0)$, otherwise the function is unbounded below.

Comment: You have to consider $b=0$ separately since $f''(x)=0$ in this case. If $b=0$ the condition is $a>0$.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&f(x)=ax^4+bx+c\\
\implies &f'(x)=4ax^3+b=0\\
\implies &f'(x_0)=0, x_0=\frac{-b}{4a}
\end{align}
Further, $f''(x)=12a x^2>0 ~for~ a > 0$.  So the mininmum of $f(x)$ is at $x=x_0$ and 
$f_{min} =f(x_0)=\frac{3b}{4} \left(\frac{-b}{4a}\right)^{1/3}+c,~ a>0.$